# What is the relationship / purpose between ClaimTypesRequested in the IP-STS and ClaimTypeRequired in the RP

Tags: adfs, adfs2.0, wif

The ClaimTypesRequested section seems to be built up from the “Claim Descriptions” tab in ADFS and the web.config and metada inherit this when “bound” via FedUtil.

- Does WIF compare the two in any way?
- Does the RP list have to be a subset?
- Are any errors thrown when “out of sync”?

e.g. you can define custom claims in the ADFS claims rules that don’t appear in either list and yet seem to get through to the RP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WIF does not validate or compare the two at any time. They are there so you can call the API so your code can validate list the claims in your app. It is very confusing. I usually just have the required ones there as "documentation" of the claims that you need.

You can find our more about Claims & WIF in our guide http://claimsid.codeplex.com. The 2nd version will be out soon.